# "Complex Projective Space" is the analytification of what?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Working through introductory course* notes on Algebraic Geometry (*thus unable to provide a link) I come across the following:

"The complex projective space $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1$ is the analytification of $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$"

The problem is, I do not know what $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$ looks like (or even its name, so I cannot search for it online).

Answer (score 3):

Presumably $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$ denotes the projective line as an algebraic variety (i.e. with the Zariski topology and the sheaf of polynomial functions).  $\mathbb{C} \mathbb{P}^1$ would then by obtained by analytifying, i.e. by putting the Euclidean topology on and allowing arbitrary analytic functions instead of polynomials.

Comment: I see, so that is why the complex subscript comes into it, brilliant; thank you!